# How to concat different parameters type in one parameter (bytes) and extract them?

Tags: solidity, bytes

I have a function that take 3 parameters

```
function askForHelp (string id, uint256 times, bytes32 signature)  {
  //do something
}
```

I want to change it to:

```
function askForHelp(bytes data) {
   string id = extractId(data);
   uint256 times = extractTimes(data);
   bytes32 signature = extractSig(data);

   //do something
}


//to implement
function extractId (bytes data) ;
//to implement
function extractTimes (bytes data) ;
//to implement
function extractSig (bytes data) ;
```

**EDIT :** 
for concatination I am plannig to make it by this way:

```
//signature is already hex
//convert **id**: string  has a fixed size = 12 characters => fix hex size

let data = signature+web3.toHex(id)+web3.toHex(times);
```

Comment: perhaps you should to split this question into two asking how to concatenate the variable and another how to extract them?

Comment: I added the way I concat data

Comment: It won't work in solidity. I assume you mean you have a frontend application that will do the concatenation. I think your question is valid but the two question are not really related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have the bytes in input in the following form:

- 12 bytes for the ID
- 32 bytes for the uint
- 32 bytes for signature

you can just create the functions in this way:

```
function extractId (bytes data) public pure returns(string) {
    bytes12 out;
    for (uint i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        out |= bytes12(data[i] & 0xFF) >> (i * 8);
    }
    bytes memory returnValue = new bytes(12);
    for (uint j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
        returnValue[j] = out[j];
    }
    return string(returnValue);
}
```

this would get the 12 bytes of your data and convert to string.

```
function extractTimes (bytes data) public pure returns(uint256) {
    uint256 number;
    for(uint i= 0;i< 32;i++){
        number = number + uint(data[12 + i])*(2**(8*(32-(i+1))));
    }

    return number;
}
```

this would take the following 32 byes (pay attention to `12 + i`) and convert to uint

```
function extractSig (bytes data) public pure returns(bytes32) {
      bytes32 out;
      for (uint i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        out |= bytes32(data[12 + 32 + i] & 0xFF) >> (i * 8);
      }
      return out;
}
```

while the signature gonna read the last 32 byes (look at `12 + 32 + i`).

```
function askForHelp(bytes data) public pure returns(string, uint256, bytes32) {
   string memory id = extractId(data);
   uint256 times = extractTimes(data);
   bytes32 signature = extractSig(data);

   return (id, times, signature);
}
```

eventually you can call it concatenating the bytes of the single parameters (ex)

```
750000000000000000000000 (12 bytes for the ID)
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c (32 bytes uint256)
7700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 (32 bytes)
```

the actual value to use to call the function `askForHelp` eventually would be just a concatenation of the previous values:

```
0x750000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c7700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```